# Vague paper submission guidelines - can I use double column if not specified?

Tags: paper-submission

I'm writing a paper for an upcoming congress and there are no author guidelines except for:

"... Articles must be single-spaced, with figures and tables included... References should be double-spaced and in alphabetical order..."

Since guidelines are so vague with respect to all other aspects, should I use any LaTeX template I wish so long as the text is single-spaced and references double-spaced?

My personal preference would be to use a double column template, but since the guidelines are so vague I'm wondering if I should just submit a single column simple manuscript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at past editions of the conference proceedings to see what style they were ultimately formatted in. Double-column (like IEEE) is typically denser than a single-column, so by picking a two-column format, you may be giving yourself some extra room that other submitters won't have. But you may lose this advantage if your paper is accepted and the format was intended to be single column, since you may have to cut something like 20% out of the content if you are already pushing the limits.